# How do I get Event Stream Rules to calculate average

Tags: drools

Am trying to get some basic examples working - so I can learn & build on before starting real project work

I have a demoApp which is inserts Integer facts into an entry-point (Stream)

In Rules (initially) am just trying to 
'detect' arrival of each new Integer event
use the sliding window & accumulate functionality to calculate a simple 3 tick average (& insertlogical this as new Facts)

Examples much appreciated

Comment: Asking for code, tutorials, or examples is off topic on StackOverflow. However if you attempt to implement the code yourself and run into difficulties we can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Have got it workings with this Rule

package tradingRules

import java.sql.Date;

import tradingRules.model.historicData.StockQuote;

declare SMA5
    date : java.sql.Date @key
    average : double 
end

declare StockQuote
  @role( event )
end

declare window StockQuoteTicks
     StockQuote() over window:length(5) from entry-point HistoricDataStream
end

rule "calculate 5 Tick Average"
    dialect "mvel"
    salience 10
    when
        $sQ : StockQuote($d1 : date) from entry-point HistoricDataStream
        Number($s : doubleValue) from accumulate($sQ2 : StockQuote() from window StockQuoteTicks, sum($sQ2.close) ) 
    then
        insertLogical(new SMA5($d1, $s / 5));
//      System.out.println( "StockQuote 5 ticks average " + $s / 5);
end